# bootstrap-table sort only visible rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hidden, tablesort

I use a button to toggle visible/hidden values in a table. This works fine but when I click on a thead data-sortable, this shows again hidden rows. How can I keep hidden rows hidden when clicking on a thead ? PS: I want to keep the values in case the user unchecks the button.

Thanks

```
<html lang='fr'>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" type="image/png" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.20.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>


    <div class='container'>

      <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
          <input id='sans-sel' type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Without
        </label>
      </div>


      <table class='table table-stripped table-bordered data-sort-name="Nom" data-sort-order="desc"' data-toggle="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th data-field="Nom" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
            <th data-field="sel" data-sortable="true">Sel</th>
            <th data-field="ca" data-sortable="true">Calcium</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>boisson amande gourmande</td>
            <td class='sel'>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>boisson amande intense</td>
            <td class='sel'>0.025</td>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>boisson amande légère</td>
            <td class='sel'>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>boisson amande sans sucre</td>
            <td class='sel'>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>DOUCEUR AMANDE CHOCOLAT</td>
            <td class='sel'>0.08</td>
            <td>110</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>NUTRI AMANDE PROTÉINES VÉGÉTALES</td>
            <td class='sel'>0.06</td>
            <td>120</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <script>
      $('#sans-sel').on('click', function() {
        const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.sel');
        Array.from(elements).forEach((element, index) => {
          //console.log(element.innerHTML);
          if (element.innerHTML != 0) {
            if (element.parentNode.style.display === 'none') {
              element.parentNode.style.display = 'table-row';
            } else {
              element.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
            }
          }
        });
      });

    </script>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.20.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/syu0qvn5/

Comment: Hi! There is the main problem Bootstrap Table deleting dynamically assigned classes. Is there any option to use another one?

Answer (score 1):

First off all there is a problem with sorting in Bootstrap Tables. It deletes all classes you've made. So you should write script after tables finish rendering.

In official documentation for Bootstrap tables you can find `onPostBody` event.
Here: https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/events/

After rendering I put script one more time for making rows visible or not. Also I'm checking flag button before it `if(document.querySelector('#sans-sel').checked){}`.

```html
<html lang='fr'>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" type="image/png" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.20.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>


    <div class='container'>

      <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
          <input id='sans-sel' type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Without
        </label>
      </div>


      <table class='table table-stripped table-bordered data-sort-name="Nom" data-sort-order="desc"' data-toggle="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th data-field="Nom" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
            <th data-field="sel" data-sortable="true">Sel</th>
            <th data-field="ca" data-sortable="true">Calcium</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>boisson amande gourmande</td>
            <td class='sel'>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>boisson amande intense</td>
            <td class='sel'>0.025</td>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>boisson amande légère</td>
            <td class='sel'>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>boisson amande sans sucre</td>
            <td class='sel'>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>DOUCEUR AMANDE CHOCOLAT</td>
            <td class='sel'>0.08</td>
            <td>110</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>NUTRI AMANDE PROTÉINES VÉGÉTALES</td>
            <td class='sel'>0.06</td>
            <td>120</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.20.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      
    $('.table').bootstrapTable({
        'onPostBody': () => { 
            
            const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.sel');
    
            elements.forEach(function(element, i){
            
                element.parentNode.style.display === 'none';
            
                if(document.querySelector('#sans-sel').checked){
                    
                    if (element.innerHTML == 0) {
                        element.parentNode.style.display = 'table-row';
                    }
                    else {
                        element.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    element.parentNode.style.display = 'table-row';
                }
            
        
            });
        },
    });
      
    document.addEventListener('click', function(el){
        const currentEl = el.target;

        if(currentEl && currentEl.id === 'sans-sel'){
            
            const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.sel');
            elements.forEach(function(element){
                if (element.innerHTML != 0) {
                    if (element.parentNode.style.display === 'none') {
                        element.parentNode.style.display = 'table-row';
                    } else {
                        element.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The table should (is?) databound on sort, or at least redrawing all the rows minus your styles.

Rather than apply styles, apply a filter to the query that limits data rows based on `sel` content after you click the *With-out* checkbox.

The best way to keep data hidden is to not include it in the first place.  Then you don't have to worry about sorting.

Comment: In this case each button click will send request to server. With JS solution it will be working on a client side.

Comment: I don't know if `bootstrap-table` hits the server db or is it just redrawing the table with some client side dataset.  In either case it cannot redraw what is not there. on checkbox click I'd filter the original dataset to a new dataset and use the filtered dataset with bootstrap-table.